# Plot of the estimated log hazard ratio in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, data-visualization, survival

Is it possible to plot the estimated log hazard ratio in R?
For example,

```
require(survival)
fit1 = coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx, ovarian)
```

Comment: Plot it how? Over time? By covariates? Just a picture of the distribution of the HR?

Comment: Isn't the estimated hazard ratio just one number?  Do you instead want a plot of the estimated baseline hazard?

Comment: I try to reproduce a similar figure on "Applied Survival Analysis" (Page 117, Figure 4.2). I believe that the authors plots the estimated log hazard ration over time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Saw this question while browsing through the survival questions and though I just post some of my personal favorites. I like using the rms package for survival functions and you could do a forestplot type of output:

```
library(survival)
library(rms)
ddist <- datadist(ovarian)
options(datadist='ddist')

ovarian$rx <- factor(ovarian$rx)
fit1 = cph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx + rcs(age, 3), ovarian, x=T, y=T)
# The plot.summary.rms
plot(summary(fit1, age=c(50,60)), q=c(.6, .8, .95), log=T, 
                 col=c("orange", "gold", "blue"))
```

gives you:

[image: plot.summary.rms]

I also like the [termplot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/termplot.html) that I've [updated slightly](http://pastebin.com/hBmStX4Y):

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
termplot2(fit1, se=T, rug.type="density", rug=T, density.proportion=.05, 
          se.type="polygon", 
          ylab=rep("Hazard Ratio", times=2),
          main=rep("cph() plot", times=2),
          col.se=rgb(.2,.2,1,.4), col.term="black")
```

that gives you this plot:

[image: termplot version]

and last but not least for a log-log plot if you wanted to look for the hazard over time as the comment suggested:

```
f <- survfit(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ rx, data=ovarian)
survplot(f, loglog=T, logt=T, xlab="log(Years)")
```

that gives:

[image: log-log survival plot]

another efficient way of looking at the hazard of time is the Schoenfeld residuals:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))
f <- cox.zph(fit1)
plot(f, resid=F)
```

that gives:

[image: Schoenfeld residuals]

Answer (score 2):

Not having a copy of Applied Survival Analysis, I'm guessing you're looking for something like this: http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=Design:hazard.ratio.plot